# Example of collection of nested intervals whose intersection is empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Give an example of intervals not empty $I_n \in \mathbb{R} (n ∈ \mathbb{N})$ which are bounded, with $I_{n + 1} \subset I_n$ for each $n$, and $\cap_{n = 1}^\infty I_n=\emptyset$.

I thought about $[n,\infty)$, but this is not bounded.

Comment: $(0,1/n)$......

Comment: I had also thought about that, but somehow the intersection gave me {0}, but I was wrong.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is not the infinite intersection because its an open interval.  Clearly 0 isnt any any of the intervals.

Answer (score 2):

For example 
$I_n=(0,\frac1n)$.

It is probably an example near some theorems about compactness, showing that the assumption, that the set are closed, is important.

Answer (score 1):

If the intervals were closed, the result will not be true (it's called Cantor's theorem, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem)). Basically, it follows from the compacity.

So you have to choose open intervals. An easy choice can be the following:

$I_n = (0,1/n)$

The intersection of all $I_n$ is empty, because if there were $x \in \cap I_n$, $x$ will be strictly greater than zero, and there will exist $n$ such that $x>1/n$, because $1/n$ converges to zero, so for this $n$, $x \notin I_n$.